# Get list of all available pip packages and their versions

Tags: python, pip, command-line-interface

I am writing a system where I need to get a list of all available packages that can be installed via the pip running on my machine and their default versions. The reason being I need a way to make a production build of my system reproducible, even if someone manually upgraded a single package for pip.

I currently have this one liner to accomplish it, but it doesn't always work cleanly and I'd prefer to steer away from text parsing if at all possible.

```
$ pip search * | awk '{print $1 $2}' | cut -d ')' -f 1 | awk -F'(' '{print $1"=="$2}'
```

Is there an easy way to do this in pip? It would be nice if there was an equivalent to `pip freeze` but for all the available packages instead of just what's installed.

Comment: I don't understand why you need *all possible* packages you can download as opposed to what is already installed on your system if your goal is to make a reproducible list of *things* to install?

Comment: @idjaw because the idea is to have a docker container which operates as a base for other containers written by anyone. Then, we can validate that containers built on top of the base with a list of all available packages from the base so we can ensure state compliance. The reason to do it this way is our production build system environment is different from each developer's build system environment so we need a way to ensure cohesion across all applications built in a production environment without having to force developers to declare versions inline

Comment: @idjaw This way, when developers are testing locally the production build system is enforced transparently

Comment: So, with this list, you are building a local repo inside this base repo? And containers pull from that? I'm not quite getting it.

Comment: Typically, each project should be self contained and your docker containers should be as self contained as well.

Comment: @idjaw Let's say the base container is an alpine container named baseapp then I have FROM baseapp:latest in my dockerfile for my application named httpapp. Then, httpapp would use the package managers (pip, apk) inherited from baseapp. This way I can develop my container with lines in my dockerfile like RUN pip install pycrypto without having to worry about versions because those versions are tracked and stored by baseapp

Comment: @idjaw however, I'm not sure how my reasons are necessarily pertinent to the question

Comment: For one I'm curious. Also, it seems like an odd setup to collect everything from pypi and get the default version which I believe is just the latest anyway? Are you looking to "freeze" versions? I am asking, because, there is something you can do that does make your life easier. You can use pip-tools to compile a list of all packages that are used and all their versions, and it even gives you an indication of where these versions are being used from and who requires them. You can read more about pip-tools here: https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [PyPI Simple API](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPISimple) on how to get the list of all available packages without versions.