# What is the best way to check if a PyPI package name is taken?

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging

What is the best way to check if a PyPI package name is taken?

Several times now I have searched [pypi](https://pypi.org/search/) for a package and received no results. Then I have taken the time to create a package with a name seemingly not taken, only to receive an error when I deploy. Is there a better way to check package name availability?

Comment: pip install <package> won't do it ? or wget https://pypi.org/project/you_project_name/. The pypi url will return 404 if its empty or 200 if its there, you can do something with the requests module to check it using head.

Comment: `pip install python` for example should work for you

Comment: As @CristianoAraujo points out the pip install or search will often show nothing even though the package name is not available. The suggestion to get pypi.org/project/you_project_name is a good one and more reliable, it seems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572503/7976758

Comment: Thanks didn't know the /simple . However are you sure it answers the question? I strongly suspect, unless I've tripped on some weird case, that a name can be denied yet not show on this search. Am I simply mistaken?

Comment: @PeterCotton AFAIK `/simple/` lists all packages.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/definetti doesn't show.

Comment: Oh I see you're hitting /simple not /simple/definetti.    That nice. Probably the solution

Answer (score 3):

I just made a python package for that same use, it's called `pkg_name_validator`.

To install it, just run

```
pip install pkg_name_validator
```

Using it is as simple as using `python -m`, like so:

```
python -m pkg_name_validator <package name to validate>
```

And if you need any help, just run:

```
python -m pkg_name_validator -h
```

Comment: Really good way to check if package name is available. Thanks :)

Comment: Doesn't address the annoying "The name '...' is too similar to an existing project" issue.

Comment: Still haven't found a workaround for that :(... I am open to suggestions though, preferably on github.

Comment: ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.0.0 Requires-Python >=3.10,<4.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg_name_validator

Comment: @Sekomer you do not have the sufficient python version. You would need to install python 3.10+ to get it to work. Hope that helps!

Comment: This package may not be very useful because it does not take into account PyPI's specification limiting packages with similar names. (e.g. `pkgnamevalidator` and `pkg-name-validator`) https://github.com/Tinkering-Townsperson/pkg_name_validator/issues/1

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it seems that is trial and error situation. Nevertheless you can always try `pip install <name_package>` to see if the name is already taken.

If you are interesting in deploying your package and don't facing up indexes errors from PyPi, you can always try out to deploy your code to `TestPyPi`. You will have to replace this first command:

`python -m twine upload --repository pypi dist/*`

by

`python -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*`

Comment: Good suggestion. It hadn't occurred to me that they must share the same namespace - but I suppose that's true? As a practical matter though, it takes a few steps to change the name of a package (maybe someone should deploy a package for that :)

Comment: TestPyPI and PyPI don't share the same namespace. Picking an arbitrary name, compare https://pypi.org/project/pyromaji/ and https://test.pypi.org/project/pyromaji/