# PyPI package name similar to existing project

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging, python-poetry

Is it possible to check whether the name of my project will be available on PyPI? Recently I got this error:

```
HTTP Error 400: The name 'my-project-name-to-be-published' is too similar to an existing project. See https://pypi.org/help/#project-name for more information.
```

So it looks like it is not only a problem of exact name match. Is there some way to check if the name will be unique enough for PyPI other then just preparing everything and then getting error like this?

Comment: Only way would be to test, as per this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70023933/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-pypi-package-name-is-taken). A few python packages have been created to answer this issue (eg check-pypi-name)

Comment: I think you are right. There is no other way. Thanks.